# sp_send_dbmail is not working

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to use [sp_send_dbmail (Transact-SQL)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190307.aspx).

The **@recipients** value is said to be *a semicolon-delimited list of e-mail addresses to send the message to.*

So, in my data table's `Email` column, all I should have to do is update the row to send to multiple recipients:

**Old:** `JoeP@jp2code.net`

**New:** `JoeP@jp2code.net; personB@jp2code.net`

There are no errors, but then there is no email going out.

The code I use to call `sp_send_dbmail` is unchanged in my stored procedure:

```
IF (0 < (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM #Email)) BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID=ID, @email=Email FROM #Email
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @recipients=@email, @subject=@subj, @body=@html, @body_format='HTML', @from_address='no-reply@jp2code.net', @reply_to=@email;
    DELETE #Email WHERE @email=Email
END
```

So, **what is wrong?**

Comment: Have you setup the smtp gateway?

Comment: Our network administrator did that. Like I said, it works fine if I use a single email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have found the issue...

```
@reply_to=@email;
```

[ @reply_to= ] 'reply_to' 
Is the value of the 'reply to address' of the email message. It accepts only one email address as a valid value. This is an optional parameter used to override the settings in the mail profile. This parameter is of type varchar(MAX). SMTP secuirty settings determine if these overrides are accepted. If no parameter is specified, the default is NULL.

This explains why it worked with a single address, but doesn't work with multiple addresses.

Comment: I was just writing that up as the found solution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake.

Take a closer look at the SQL:

```
IF (0 < (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM #Email)) BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @ID=ID, @email=Email FROM #Email
    EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
            @recipients=@email, 
            @subject=@subj, 
            @body=@html, 
            @body_format='HTML', 
            @from_address='no-reply@jp2code.net', 
            @reply_to=@email;
    DELETE #Email WHERE @email=Email
END
```

Does everyone see the problem now?

*Hint: Look at the `reply_to` field.*